# Is an actionscript 'Number' like a Java 'double'?

Tags: java, actionscript, precision

Can a Number in actionscript hold the same amount of and precision of values like a double in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is! According to spec `Number` is:

> A data type representing an IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point number. You can manipulate primitive numeric values by using the methods and properties associated with the Number class. This class is identical to the JavaScript Number class.

Some references:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64
- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3

Comment: yep, but later it says: "The Number data type can use up to 53 bits to represent integer values" shouldnt it be 64 bits?

Comment: Yes and no. It is 64 bit, but can only represent integers up to 53... Java `double` is falls into same category by spec :) http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3